# App to View OpenDocument Presentation file (ODP) on a phone/tablet

Tags: android, ios, documentation-viewer

A "report" from a recent event was sent to participants in the form of an OpenDocument Presentation Document Format (ODP).

(the "free" equivalent for PowerPoint, as used by LibreOffice and OpenOffice programs)

The presentation is mostly photos taken at the event, maybe some shot videos too.

How to view the file on a phone?

I am asking for both Android and iPhone (and iPad).

I tried the often recommended OOReader app ([appstore link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ooreader/id480844649)) on iPhone, but it has a file size limit of 20 MB and our presentation file is bigger. Similar is the [Libre Office viewer Lite](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/libre-office-viewer-lite/id1510195065) app, it crashes a few seconds after opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [OpenDocument Reader](https://opendocument.app/)? Apart from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.tomtasche.reader) and [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1452061743?mt=8), it's also available [on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/at.tomtasche.reader/), although the upstream code is not entirely free.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It crashes, just like the Lite version I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidBalažic _OOReader_ and _OpenDocument Reader_ are two different apps, have you tried them both?

Comment: Yes, I tried the app you linked in the answer. "OpenDocument Reader" or as it is called in the app store: Libre Office: Document reader

Comment: There is another app: Google Docs is available on [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/google-docs/id842842640) and on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs) (obviously), it [should support ODF](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2014/12/complete-odf-file-format-support-and.html)